# C# class property with "two types"

Tags: c#, getter-setter

I there any way in c# to create a property which will be basically a `bool` but can be set via `string`?
What I want to achive is simple:

```
string stringValue = "true";
object.BoolValue = stringValue ;
bool boolValue = object.BoolValue;
```

My idea was using `get; set;` but it always crashes on conversion. I can convert that `string` in object constructor but what if I want to change it later? Do I need a separate method for conversion (it is not only "true"/"false" but in that setter there should be a list of true values and false values and the rest is argument exception)?

Thanks for any ideas on how to achive this.

**UPDATE: Code from OPs comment**

```
private bool _readOnly;

public bool ReadOnly {
    get => _readOnly;
    set => _readOnly = Convert.ToBoolean(value);
}

public DeviceProperty(string readOnly) {
    ReadOnly = readOnly;
}
```

**UPDATE: Solution**

Down here you can find a solution with explicit conversion which would works just fine in my application. But regarding best practices in programming I created method to set internal boolean to true/false and then can read it normally.

```
string stringValue = "true";
_ = object.SetBoolValue = stringValue ;
bool boolValue = object.BoolValue;


public bool SetBoolValue(string stringValue)
{
    string[] trueValues = ..........
    string[] falseValues = .........

    if(trueValues contains stringValue)
    {
        BoolValue = true;
        return true;
    }
    if(falseValues contains stringValue)
    {
        BoolValue = false;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Most important for me is a possibility to create logical operation on this boolValue easily so that is the reason I created Set method and not Get method.

**UPDATE: Solution 2...**

I am not publishing any code here again but just an update that my last statement about storing as bool to have easier access to logical operations on it shown to be wrong. Because "one changes its mind" and the lists of true and false values change. All the time. And also the way you would not expected. Something what was false is now true etc... And the result bool has to be set based on current setup not something from yesterday. So the object remembers string value and have method GetBool() to say if its true or not based on current lists...

Comment: `Convert.ToBoolean(stringValue)` should do.

Comment: Not really. That supposed internal variable is string. So I can set it easily but return this way will throw an conversion exception.

Comment: Please show the code that throws. From your pseudo-code it's hard to find out what problem you are facing.

Comment: `       private bool _readOnly;

        public bool ReadOnly
        {
            get => _readOnly;
            set => _readOnly = Convert.ToBoolean(value);
        }

        public DeviceProperty(string readOnly)
        {

            ReadOnly = readOnly;

        }`

Instead of the simple conversion there will be some logic. Sorry I do not know why it is not fomating as a code...

Comment: Frst off: please edit your *question* to include code. It's hard to read code in comments. Second: `value` is a `bool`, not a `string`.  Third: Why do you have a property named `ReadOnly` that is publicly writable? It's still hard to underdstand what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: @JanDaliba what's the *actual* problem you want to solve? You can't set a property using a different type unless there's an implicit conversion, which means the value gets converted before it's set. There's no implicit conversion from string to bool. In what language would the conversion be? Which words? `1`, `Yes`, `True`? What about `Banana` ?

Comment: Converting between strings and object properties is the job of serializers, not the properties themselves. There are more than one possible formats or conversions. You shouldn't have to modify your DTOs or entities when you decide to add JSON, XML, YAML or Protobuf serialization

Comment: You could have a methos `SetBoolValue(string)`, but the most important question here is "why". Why do you need to do this?

Comment: That is exactly a problem. I do not know the true and false values before specific implementation. Then I want to set them in external config and during each assigment check them. This is simple but there will need to be an method object.SetReadOnlyValue("Banana"). Which will set the internal property. I just wanted to avoid it and try to assign it directly and the make the setter do the magic.

Comment: So you want to call a function in your setter that verifies if the incoming string-value represents a "valid" bool-value as of your config, correct?

Comment: @JanDaliba even more reason to *NOT* put the logic in the class itself. You still haven't explained the problem, only how you assume it's solved. Whatever it is, it won't be solved like this. .NET itself uses binders and converters to bind strongly-typed models to UIs, or serialize objects to various formats. The converter/binder can use any configuration you want without breaking the models/entities

Comment: Why everyone wants to know Why? what it changes? I have an external source of objects. XML file.  I am mining there some attributes and nodes.. and based on result I am changing this object properties. So from xml there is always a string value like  that "banana".  but for me it is only true/false value. one of many true/false values. Afterwards I am reading object properties as Boolean and making some decisions based on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't modify built-in types but you can create a new type that defines **Implicit Operator** inside and you can set both string and bool to this type.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators

Also you can define an **Explicit operator** too, to cast your object to both of types without actually casting.

```cs
public struct MyBoolString
{
    private bool _value;

    public static implicit operator MyBoolString(bool value)
    {
        return new MyBoolString { _value = value };
    }

    public static implicit operator bool(MyBoolString value)
    {
        return value._value;
    }

    public static implicit operator MyBoolString(string value)
    {
        return new MyBoolString { _value = bool.Parse(value) };
    }

    public static implicit operator string(MyBoolString value)
    {
        return value._value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like that

```
MyBoolString myBoolString = "true";
myBoolString = true;

bool myBool = myBoolString;
string myString = myBoolString;
```

And as a property:

```cs
public MyBoolString Foo { get; set; }
```

> **WARNING:** This might be not the best practice for your situation. If you create a new type that means you have to handle serialization & deserialization logic of the type. I.E. database providers can't know your custom type or use it in the wrong way. It's not suggested as a best practice if you use the approach to carry data.

Comment: Please don't do this with strings...

Comment: I also don't suggest using it either, especially working with database providers, But it's possible what you asked in the question

Comment: we have a duty of care to the community to educate readers on how to write higher quality code, By answering questions from beginners in ways that allow them to operate outside of the conventions of the language we are setting them up for failure in the future. While it is possible, it does not mean this is best practice. If noobs see the _tick_ they will assume incorrectly that this is a good solution. That is not a legacy I would want to be associated with.

Comment: I can't know the context. In a particular context, it can be useful. For example, Unity uses custom operators and custom overridden Equals methods in its game objects to improve developer experience. But if you only carry data please use classic POCO classes.

Comment: I agree @ChrisSchaller by the way 

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer is *NO* and that this is generally unnecessary because the caller can use what ever mechanism they need to cast or convert the input value to the property value on your `Type`.

I would advise against setting implicit types for primitive values or specifically strings. The failure domain is so large and you move conversion checks from compile time to runtime that it is hard to enforce quality of your code.

It is a far better design to force the caller to manage the value conversion and handle the errors than it is to try and do the same thing implicitly inside your class where you have no concept of the active context or a way to communicate back to the caller gracefully.

We can however use multiple properties to se the same underlying field, or we could use an additional method to set the *string* version of the value and convert it.

> **NOTE:**
> It is hard to determine your reasoning for trying to implement this at all. A primary concern in applications is data consistency, so your `Type` should define the only acceptable input type, plowing multiple ways to set the same field can be ambiguous is any value accepted, but only values that can be parsed to the underlying type valid in the typed property? Should it throw an exception of type conversion fails or should the typed value remain default?

```
public class BoolValue
{
    private bool _boolValue;
    public string AsString
    { 
        get => _boolValue.ToString();
        // Will throw exception if the string was not a valid bool
        set => _boolValue = Boolean.Parse(value);
    }
    public string AsSafeString
    { 
        get => _boolValue.ToString(); 
        set
        {
            if (Boolean.TryParse(value, out bool b)
                _boolValue = b;
        }
    }
    public bool Value
    {
        get => _boolValue; 
        set => _boolValue = value;
    }
}
```

You can see we can create a number of properties that all set the same field. You could also have used specific methods instead of properties, this makes a lot more sense for supporting setting the value from other types but the whole concept is still a huge code smell.

Reversing the storage model is not much better, but if the input string values might be other non-boolean values and you need to retain them then you could use an implementation like this:

```
public class BoolValue
{
    private string _inputValue;
    public string AsString
    { 
        get => _inputValue;
        set => _inputValue = value;
    }
   
    public bool? Value
    {
        get => Boolean.TryParse(_inputValue, out bool b) ? b : (bool?)null;
        set => _inputValue = value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A property that gets its value from that field for instance?

```
class MyClass
{
    string myString = "true";
    bool myBool => Convert(myString);
    bool Convert(string myString) => 
        myString.ToLower() == "true" || 
        myString == "1" 
        /* ||  further truish expressions */ ;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are trying to achieve something like this?

```cs
class Foo
{
    private bool _boolean;

    public string StringBoolean
    {
        get
        {
            return _boolean ? "true" : "false";
        }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals("true")) _boolean = true;
            else if (value.Equals("false")) _boolean = false;
            else throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But this would return a string "true"/"false". I want a boolean. I thought it is not possible to do it this way, it would just be nice.. this implicit conversion on property.